# Python script directory get last modified for files and folders

Tags: python, directory

```
def list_folders(path, dest_output):
    dir_entries = os.scandir(path)
    complete_path = os.path.join(dest_output, "folder_names.txt")
    for entry in dir_entries:
        if entry.is_file():
            info = entry.stat()
            with open(complete_path, "w") as f_output:
                f_output.write(f'{entry.name}\t \t Last Modified: {convert_date(info.st_mtime)}')
```

I am looking to get the file as well as folder names for a specific directory(basically everything). I also want to print the last modified next to each name. I am able to get the file names but not the folder names. `convert_date`  is just a function created to get the date into a specific format.

Comment: `entry` should have an `is_dir` method. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes. It does not give all the files and folders

Comment: Works on my system. There is also an `is_symlink` method on `entry`. Is it possible your folder contains symbolic links? What operating system are you running? Have you tried logging every entry by removing the `is_file` condition?

Comment: i am using Windows 10. What do you mean by logging every entry?

Comment: Remove `if entry.is_file():` so that every entry is written to the file. Each `entry` should either be a file, a folder, or a symbolic link.